# syntax error during py2app build

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to programming (so please bear with me), but loving it so far. I coded a game using pygame and am having trouble compiling it as a stand-alone application using py2app. I'm using Macports Python 2.7, though I tried switching back to the default Mac installation (2.7) as well as the default 2.6 and still get this error during the py2app build:

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/mpmath/libmp/exec_py3.py", line 1
    exec_ = exec
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Exec_py3.py consists of all of one line:

```
exec_ = exec
```

Just for laughs I commented it out and the py2app proceeded further along in the build but then choked here:

```
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 304, in synchronize_size
    raise ValueError("New Mach-O header is too large to relocate")
ValueError: New Mach-O header is too large to relocate
```

I don't know if the issues are related.  Py2app is working fine for a couple little test scripts I wrote that don't use pygame. Any suggestions for what I can try next?

Thanks!

edit - I found a couple of links that may be related, but can't really understand what's going on in the conversation.  Can anyone translate for a relative newby?

http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/issues/detail?id=204

https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issue/93/mach-o-header-may-be-too-large-to-relocate

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround in case anybody else runs into this. I uninstalled MacPorts and just used the Mac system Python (2.7). Everything then compiled fine. It was not enough just to use the port select command to switch to the system Python; I had to deinstall the whole thing.